# I have 2 RecyclerViews in a Fragment. But only the 1st one is shown

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to have two RecyclerViews in a Fragment. One of them being a horizontally aligned RecyclerView, and the other a vertically aligned one. But only the horizontal RecyclerView is visible. (The vertical RecyclerView is visible if I change the order of the RecyclerViews in the layout file, so I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the RecyclerViews.)

As per other answers to similar questions, I've added the `layout_weight=1` in both the RecyclerViews. But the 2nd RecyclerView still doesn't show.

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/CategoryPageRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/ItemsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have a feeling the SwipeRefreshLayout is causing an issue. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SwipeRefreshView` supports only one direct child - wrap `RecyclerView`s in `LinearLayout` and it will work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/CategoryPageRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/ItemsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps you, comment if you have any questions

Comment: It does work! Thanks a lot :)
By the way, how can I avoid giving half the window to the horizontal RecyclerView?

Comment: Edit your weights or remove them entirely and set first's height to something in dp (`android:layout_height="100dp"`) and second to `match_parent`

Comment: You can accept the answer so that other people who find this will immediately know the answer worked in your case - it's under the vote buttons